# $(M,d)$ be a complete metric space and $N \subset M$ a closed subset $\Rightarrow N$ is complete

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

$(M,d)$ be a complete metric space and $N \subset M$ a closed subset $\Rightarrow N$ is complete

**proof**

take a Cauchy sequence in $(N,d)$ then this Cauchy sequence converges in $M$ since M is complete. Now we need to show that this convergence occurs in $N$. Since $N$ is closed, $\cdot\cdot\cdot$

**Question**
Any hint to proceed above reasoning?

Comment: Reason that the point of convergence of that sequence in $M$ is a limit point of $N$

Comment: hii@Daschin if u accept my answer plzz click on the tick button. I am short of reputations.. It's a request..

Comment: See also [Showing that if a subset of a complete metric space is closed, it is also complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/244661) and [Proof that a subspace $A$ of a complete metric space $X$ is complete iff $A$ is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/243199).

Answer (score 0):

Since $N$ is closed, the limit point has to lie in $N$. If not, then you can find some small open ball in $M\setminus N$ containing the limit point. But by definition of a limit point, this implies that...?

Comment: a set $A $is closed $\Rightarrow$ any limit points of A lies in A. Is it trivial fact?

Comment: @Daschin What is your definition of a closed subset of a metric space?

Comment: when its complement($M\setminus A$) is open, we call it closed

Comment: @Daschin When does a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $M$ converge to a point $x\in M$?

Comment: when for $n > N$, if $d(x_n , x)<e$ $\forall$ $e\gt0$.

Comment: @Daschin No, if for every $e>0$ there exists some $N$ such that $d(x_n,x) < e$ for all $n> N$. What can you conclude if the open ball in my answer is of the form $B_e(x)=\{y\in M: d(x,y)< e\}$?

Answer (score 0):

If $\left\{x_n \right\}$ is Cauchy sequence in $M$, so it is Cauchy sequence in $N$. Since N is complete, so $\exists x_0 \in N$ such that $x_n \to x_0$. If $x_0 \notin M$, since $N-M$ is opened and $x_0 \in N-M$, so $\exists r >0$ such that $B(x_0, r) \subset N-M$. Therefore $\exists n_0 \in N^* : \forall n > n_0, x_n \in M$, irrationally. So $x_0 \in M$.

Comment: one can't use the fact N is complete before prove it

Comment: @ Daschin I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's Say $N$ is not complete. Then we can say there exist a Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $N$ which does not converge in $N$. But it must have a limit point $l$ in $M$ since $M$ is complete. so $l$ does not belong to $N$. Then we can conclude $N$ is not closed. Contrapositively we can say If $N$ is closed in $M$, $N$ is complete